# Optimize zero checks in WinMIPS64

Tags: assembly, mips

Consider the following code in WinMIPS64, that increases $s0, if $t0 is zero:

```
bnez  $t0, nonzero   ;branch if $t0 is non-zero
daddi $s0, $s0, 1    ;increment zero-count $s0 if zero
nonzero:
```

The problem with this code is that a branch delay is generated in the pipeline, until the outcome of the branch is known.
$t0 can change elsewhere in the code and this snippet can be looped.

Any ideas on how to make a more optimized zero counter?

By the way, no hardware optimizations (forwarding, branch target buffer, delay slot) are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it could be done even more efficiently, but wouldn't something like this work:

```
SLTIU $t1,$t0,1  ; set $t1 = 1 if $t0 is unsigned less than 1 (i.e. if it's 0),
                 ; otherwise set $t1 = 0
DADD $s0,$s0,$t1
```

Comment: Hi Michael and thanks for the reply.
I'll modify my code and check what happens with the stalls!

Comment: I checked it Michael. If you use your version in an unrolled loop, it will eliminate any best/worst case scenarios, which would depend on whether $t0 is actually zero. That is, it gives more consistent cycle count, so I like it!